# NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments. Receiver: _

Tags: flutter, api, dart

```
 Future getcategory() async {
await post(BASEURL + 'getCategory', body: {
  'user_id': StaticData.userid,
}).then((value) {
  return c.Category.getuserid(value);
});
```

}
[image]

this is the error that occurred while debugging and perhaps is the reason why my app wasn't able to fetch data from server

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your dart code, not PHP so please remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try by `encoding` your body in `json` format

```
 body: jsonEncode({
  'user_id': StaticData.userid,
})
```

and also `parse` the `String` into `URI` format

```
Uri.parse(BASEURL + 'getCategory');
```